# Why does my iPhone 4S think I'm in Chicago?

Tags: iphone, timezone

I live in East TN but when I change my time settings to automatic, it says I'm in Chicago.  I have to manually set it to Atlanta so that I don't get the Central time zone.

Before, it used to use Houston. So all I my google business searches would default to Houston.

Is there any way I can convince this phone I live in Hixson, TN?

Comment: I wrote a big response regarding wifi triangulation and access point location registration and what not, but I would think that iPhones' would get time zone data from cell towers/carriers, and everything else would do it's best otherwise to get location / else default to Cupertino and have you manually choose it.

I'm not sure, so I'm not answering.

Answer (score 3):

The iPhone (like pretty much all cell phones that support this feature) gets its timezone information from the carrier. Unfortunately many carriers send out the wrong timezone information and there's very little you can do about it other than switch off the Set Automatically option in the Date & Time settings.

Comment: You couldn't call the carrier? Surely this is a larger problem than just a customer-end one.

Comment: Have you ever dealt with AT&T?

Answer (score 2):

We went by car from Eastern time (Tallahassee FL) to Central time (St. Louis)), my iphone 4S changed at the time zone border, on the way back my wife's iphone 4S switched exactly at the timezone border, but mine, now a day later still shows Chicago time (both phones are on the newest OS),

Powering down (pressing home and side button) and up again remedied the problem (now back on New York time, why not Atlanta is a mystery to me).

Answer (score 0):

On mime the workaround is to switch the event to all day then switch it back and it is correct,,

Answer (score 0):

Your carrier is using a proxy ...verify this by checking your ip address location on your  phone. It will likely show you the area where all your internet activity is getting filtered through.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to Google maps and look at your location and then do your search or if you're using a browser search keyword and then put a ZIP Code in there